# How to get IP/MAC Address of any blackberry device?

Tags: blackberry

I want to find IP/MAC Address of any blackberry device so how should i get it programatically.please help me.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String getIPAddress() {

int apnId = 0;
try {
    apnId = RadioInfo.getAccessPointNumber("MagicRudyAPN.rim");
} catch (RadioException e) {
    Log.e(e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}

byte[] ipByte = RadioInfo.getIPAddress(apnId);
String ip = "";
for (int i = 0; i < ipByte.length; i++) {
    int temp = (ipByte[i] & 0xff);
    if (i < 3)
        ip = ip.concat("" + temp + ".");
    else {
        ip = ip.concat("" + temp);
    }
}

Log.s(TAG + "Returning IP=" + ip);
return ip;
```

}

refer [wifi-ip-address](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/wifi-ip-address/m-p/374279)

Comment: what is this MagicRudyAPN.rim.because above code returning ip address as 0.0.0.0 every time

Comment: Can i know that how should i retrieve MAC address of device?-

Answer (score 0):

I found this code, works fine for me...

```
protected String getIpAddress() {
    String ip = new String("");

    try {
        int cni = RadioInfo.getCurrentNetworkIndex();
        int apnId = cni + 1; // cni is zero based
        byte[] ipaddr = RadioInfo.getIPAddress(apnId);
        for (int i = 0; i < ipaddr.length; i++) {
            int temp = (ipaddr[i] & 0xff);
            if (i < 3) {
                ip = ip.concat("" + temp + ".");
            } else {
                ip = ip.concat("" + temp);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ip = null;
    }
    return ip;
}
```

Refer: [BlackBerry forum](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-get-IP-address-in-BB/td-p/381212)